# Sorting the list of objects in Python is failing

Tags: python, class, sorting, object

I have created the class named points. Which has 2 'begin' and 'end' (It basically represents a 2D co-ordinate).In the driver I've made a list of objects, I'm accepting few values and i want to sort the list of the objects according to the 'end' attribute.

This is the code:-

```
class points:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.begin=a
        self.end=b

t=int(input())
while t:
    t-=1
    l=[]
    index=[]
    n=int(input())

    for i in range(n):
        a,b=input().split()
        l.append(points(a,b))

    l=sorted(l, key=lambda obj: obj.end)


    for i in range(n):
        print(l[i].begin,l[i].end)
```

for the input:

```
1
3
5 8
9 12
6 11
```

This should be the answer:

```
5 8
6 11
9 12
```

But it is giving the answer:

```
6 11
9 12
5 8
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: `l.append(points(int(a),int(b)))`

Comment: you're currently sorting lexographically because the `a` and `b` inputs are strings not integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a,b=input().split()
this above line returns two "strings" not "integers". So a text based comparison is being used. (11 is lesser than 8 in text comparison)

Convert a and b to integer before passing it to points class or convert it to int inside of **init** of points class.